# Setting php variable in navigation menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a navigation menu (menu inside menu) like this:

```
<nav id="ml-menu" class="menu">
    <div class="menu__wrap">
        <ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-label="All">
            <li class="menu__item" role="menuitem"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-1" aria-owns="submenu-1" href="./index.php?lvl=AP">AP</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul data-menu="submenu-1" id="submenu-1" class="menu__level" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-label="Vegetables">
            <li class="menu__item" role="menuitem"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-1-1" aria-owns="submenu-1-1" href="./index.php?lvl=AP">AP1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want to set a PHP vriable while clicking a menu-item and it works only if i remove the `data-submenu` which means i want be able to navigate to the second menu.

I use `$_GET['lvl']` to read my variable.

Any ideas on how to solve this, or do it in another way ?

My js code:

```
<script>
    (function() {

        var menuEl = document.getElementById('ml-menu'),
            mlmenu = new MLMenu(menuEl, {
                backCtrl : false, // show back button
                onItemClick: loadDummyData // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked - onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
            });

        // mobile menu toggle
        var openMenuCtrl = document.querySelector('.action--open'),
            closeMenuCtrl = document.querySelector('.action--close');

        openMenuCtrl.addEventListener('click', openMenu);
        closeMenuCtrl.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);



        function openMenu() {
            classie.add(menuEl, 'menu--open');
            closeMenuCtrl.focus();
        }

        function closeMenu() {
            classie.remove(menuEl, 'menu--open');
            openMenuCtrl.focus();
        }

        var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');

        function loadDummyData(ev, itemName) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            closeMenu();

            gridWrapper.innerHTML = '';
            classie.add(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
            setTimeout(function() {
                classie.remove(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
                $('#table_id').DataTable();

                gridWrapper.innerHTML = 'some code...'

            }, 700);

        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately its unclear what you're asking. You want to set a PHP Variable while clicking a Menu-Item? The url you posted should enable you to read `$_GET['lvl']` in your php code and it will have the value `AP`.

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to set a PHP vriable while clicking a menu-item,  the above code returns an empty variable when reading wirh `$_GET['lvl']`

Comment: `data-submenu` is responsible for showing a submenu on hover? If this is the case a PHP variable can only be set if you actually make the request to the server (i.e. click the link).

Comment: `data-submenu`is responsible for showing a submenu by clicking. yet i'm still getting an empty variable.

Comment: The code in the question can only result in a PHP variable `$_GET['lvl']` with a value of `AP`. If it does not, something important is missing in the question. Is the anchor ever opened or are there JS event handlers that prevent openeing the target URL at all? Or is the target URL rewriteen by some JS script before it is requested? Or, or, or… – as you can see, you will need to provide more details, as of now, the problem is not related to the code posted above.

Comment: I added the js code. thank you.

Comment: It also works when i open the menuitem in new page.